# EXTJS - Ext.require and onReady() for inner scripts

Tags: extjs, onready

I have an app.js file which is loaded from main html file. Now this app.js file upon click of links defined in it, dynamically loads second js file using Ext.require(). Loading happens ok as I have defined Ext.Loader.setPath() etc, the second script contains lines such as Ext.require() to import some ui libraries and followed by onReady(), my problem is onReady is never fired, and I cannot put widget rendering code outside onReady(). does onReady works only for synchronous loading of scripts?

Thanks much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

onReady will only ever fire a single time for your application.

If you look at the docs you'll see Ext.require() can take a callback function:

```
Ext.require('My.foo.Bar', function() {
    console.log('do something');
});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-require

Comment: thanks that does the job! before this i was relying on jQuery's getScript()

Comment: above code works well on Chrome and Mozilla but in IE i get "Webpage error details
Message: 'processed' is null or not an object
Line: 101634
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: ext-all-debug.js
"

Answer (score 2):

As Evan says, Ext.onReady will only fire for the load of the HTML page the first time round.

If you're using ExtJS 4 then the loading of your scripts from the app.js will normally fall into an MVC pattern.

What this means in practical is that your controllers are initialised from your app.js and then these controllers are responsible for handling your code which you'd normally put inside a onReady() to bind functions to events. The concept of 'views' is where you'd put your widget code.

E.g.

**app.js**

```
Ext.application({
name: 'MyApp',
appFolder: '/MyApp/Scripts',
autoCreateViewport: true,
requires: [
    //data
    'ALES.controller.MyController',
]
});
```

**MyController.js**

```
Ext.define('ALES.controller.MyController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

id: 'MyController',
views: [
    'MyView'
],
stores: [
    'MyStore'
],
init: function () {
    this.control(
        {
            'panel > button': { click: this.myClickHandler }
        });

});
```

**MyView.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

id: 'MyView',

requires: [
    'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing' //or other Ext stuff you want to include
],

constructor: function (config) {
    this.initConfig(config);
    return this.callParent(arguments);
},

initComponent: function () {

    Ext.apply(this, {
        items: this.createControls()
    });

    this.callParent();

},

createControls: function() {
    return [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button'                
        }]

    }
    ];
}
});
```

The are some decent guides on the sencha site which I'd recommend reading through for a deeper understanding:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/application_architecture

Comment: thanks for very simplified example on mvc, mine is very close to this, but probably i can better make like this.